# Browser says function not referenced

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have been knocking my head over this. I do not want to go through PHP functions to create cookies. The javascript functions are defined just above inside a Jquery document ready. JQuery libraries are loaded just about all those javascript functions.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    function superadmin()
    {
        document.cookie = "user=superadmin";
        window.location = "list.php";
    }

    function user()
    {
        document.cookie = "user=user";
        window.location = "list.php";
    }       
  });
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $( document ).ready(function() { 
    superadmin(); 
  });
</script>    

<div class="container">
```

Comment: The `superadmin` function is only known inside the first `$( document ).ready(function() {...})` block. It does not exist outside of it, so you can not call it from the second `$( document ).ready(function() {...})` block.

Comment: Can you move superadmin and user functions to out? Not inside document.ready

Comment: I have removed superadmin and user functions out as you suggested cbalakus and works fine now. Can you post your answer below so that i can mark it as solved ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function declarations are scoped to the function they are declared in.

`superadmin` is defined in an anonymous function that is passed to `ready()` so can't be called outside of that anonymous function.

**First**, delete this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $( document ).ready(function() { 
    superadmin(); 
  });
</script>
```

**Second**, put the call to `superadmin();` **inside the existing** ready event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

this is a problem related to javascript's scope. A jquery document.ready event use a seperate scope, so if you create a variable there, it can't be accessed from other places.

A solution to this is to create a namespace, which in this situation is an object where you attach the variable. The above problem could be solved this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var Namespace = {};

$( document ).ready(function() {

  Namespace.superadmin = function()
  {
    document.cookie = "user=superadmin";
    window.location = "list.php";
  }

  Namespace.user = function()
  {
    document.cookie = "user=user";
    window.location = "list.php";
  }       
});
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$( document ).ready(function() { 
  Namespace.superadmin(); 
});
</script>    

<div class="container">
```

EDIT:

For the specific situation above, the solution posted by Quentin is better. This is an acceptable solution assuming that you can't avoid having two seperate listeners (maybe in different files). You can of course also use a scope that is accessible from both scopes, which in this situation is the window scope.

Comment: You've got a lot of red herrings in here. The solution you are really demonstrating is to *use a global* and you are throwing namespaces in the mix so you use one global instead of two (because globals are troublesome and the fewer you have the better), but there is no need to use any globals. The use of `document.ready` around the function definitions is utterly pointless here — just defining a function needs no DOM access, so waiting for the DOM to finish building before defining the functions is bloat.

Comment: Of course it's better to not use globals, but if you have the need to keep things in seperate files or listeners, then this would be an acceptable option, i think. However i agree that put the function call in just one listener is way better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not in the same scope, try this:

```
superadmin = function()
```

instead of

```
function superadmin()
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp for more details

Answer (score -1):

I have done cookes in javascript by this way

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}

 setCookie("userid",14);
 setCookie("username","rajesh");

var userid = getCookie("userid");
var username = getCookie("username");
```

Comment: This code (a) doesn't address the actual problem and (b) doesn't attempt to do what the existing code is trying to do

Comment: but sir i just want to tell him how i have implemented this in proper way:- you can check here :- https://sabakuch.com/music/